# Changed Font seems to have destroyed formatting Friggeri CV

Tags: formatting, friggeri-cv

I've been trying to use the Friggeri CV, and looked at all the bugs that people have had, so changed the font from Helvetica Neue to the the Roboto font, in the friggeri-cv.cls file. However, this little action has had the following effect:
[image]

which is clearly not the best! Does anyone know why this has happened and how to fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: Just tested with the version from l-templates. Nothing out of the ordinary, everything looks as expected. Since there are by now a myriad of `friggeri-cv` classes out there ... i vote to close as unclear.